# SSL Endpoints on Heroku and MongoLab

Tags: mongodb, ssl, heroku

I'm using CloudFlare to get free SSL coverage for a domain I own on GoDaddy. That's great and if you haven't checked out those services you might find them handy to use.  I do have a question though, I'd like to provide HTTPS/SSL encryption for data transmitted from my MongoLab DB to my Heroku App.  Both of these are through Heroku.  So,

(1) Do I need additional SSL encryption to protect the sensitive data I'll be transmitting between those two endpoints?

(2) How do I go about acquiring that?

(3) If yes to (1) and no good answer for (2), what's an alternative (nearly free) option to accomplish the same thing.  I'm not wed to MongoDB for this project.

Thanks in advance and hope this question helps someone else out as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, Heroku maintains that if you provision a MongoLab DB through them (and not through MongoLab directly) and have your Heroku app in the same AWS region you're fine as no packet sniffing can occur.

Otherwise you can purchase separate SSL encryption.

I've also decided to encrypt the data going into my database as well.

Comment: Hey Adam, your Heroku app and MongoLab database are hosted in the same AWS datacenter so the traffic between the two never leaves the datacenter. AWS has technology in place to prevent packet sniffing, however you can also purchase SSL to further secure communications with encryption. Also, if you provision a database through MongoLab directly in the *same datacenter as your Heroku app*, it is the same as provisioning a database as an add-on.